# Is this type of search engine friendly URL an SEO advantage I should use? Is it more professional?

Tags: asp.net, search-engine, friendly-url, seo

As many know, with IIS 7, it gives you the option of changing URLs to what the end-user (and presumably, googlebots, yahoobots, etc., would see.

For instance, if I can change the url -- www.mysite.com/aboutuss.aspx is it (recommended) to change that to www.mysite.com/aboutuss ?  Is this worth anything, or is it just a waste of time?

Additionally, is it worth it to change www.mysite.com/products/default.aspx to www.mysite.com/products/exclusive_products ?

Is this more professional?  Is changing this better for search engines?  Is the default.aspx a bunch of junk that I should replace with a key-phrase for SEs?

Thanks for your time in reading this, and any input would be greatly appreciated!

Jason Weber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the existence of a file extension will not hurt or improve your search rankings in any way whatsoever, unless the extension is of a file type that might be specifically what the user was looking for (PDFs for example, are often searched for when someone looks for a whitepaper).

There are some things you can do however, let's look at one of your examples:

> http://www.mysite.com/products/default.aspx

While the `default.aspx` does not hurt anything, it is potentially a missed opportunity to give additional information about what is found at this location. Your first example improvement has a problem though:

> http://www.mysite.com/products/exclusive_products

You've re-used a word twice there (products) which some believe may be seen as excessive or redundant by some search engines. Perhaps a better alternative would be:

> http://www.mysite.com/products/exclusive/

or if you don't want to remove file extensions:

> http://www.mysite.com/products/exclusive.aspx

Now you have a URL that signifies that the page includes "products" and that this is the "exclusive" subset of those products.

Non only will this potentially help with search rankings, but also could provide some additional context to your website visitors.

Comment: Wow Free-dom, that was a motherload of information that just taught me a ton!  I completely understand what you're saying, and it makes perfect sense.  In fact, I'm going to change my URLs, so make 'em more "friendly" in the way you suggested.  I might put a little more thought into the actualy key word/phrase, and avoid that duplicate content.  Thanks a bunch, free-dom, for taking the time to guide me here, and teach me a thing or two in the process.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

File extensions generally do not hurt SEO.  What does matter is keywords.

For example, I've seen improvements in Page Rank when changing:

```
mysite.com/default.aspx to mysite.com/keyword.aspx
```

that are very comparable to changing from

```
mysite.com/default.asp -> mysite.com/keyword
```

This would imply that the answer to your first question is that you will not get much additional benefit from the change.

For your second question, since you are adding additional keywords ("exclusive") that matter to your ***users*** and thus presumably are important for the particular page you are looking at, it would have a positive benefit to SEO.   Just don't go overboard with keywords and start stuffing URL's with lots of extra words.

Ultimately, for question 2, the answer is highly dependent on your SEO strategy (keywords focused on, SEO versus SEM optimization, etc).   And don't forget your user, ultimately if you do things better for them, Search Engine Rankings will improve.

P.S. Regardless of what you do, don't forget to handle redirects from the Old URL in an appropriate way - don't waste any of that SEO juice you may have already gotten!

Comment: I think your advice is tremendous, OpenR.  Your advice is very similar to the advice Free-dom offered, and it's great advice.  I'm going to make the changes you two suggested as soon as I get the chance.  But more importantly, I thank you guys for teaching me something that I can build upon.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out -- just as with Free-dom, I sincerely appreciate it.